# Encoding excerpts from collection of objects that do not themselves conform to NSCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, nscoding

I would like to serialize excerpts from a collection of objects that do not themselves conform to `NSCoding` to a file. What's the best way to achieve this without transformation the collected objects an intermediary representation (one that would conform to `NSCoding`)? The (apparent) problem arises, because `NSKeyedArchiver` requires unique keys, and there is no `NSArchiver` on iOS.

For instance, the following will not work, because values are overwritten inside the loop as keys are reused. Calculating unique key strings from some loop index would be possible but quite a nuisance:

```
for (MyObject *object in myObjects) {
    NSString *someString = myObject.someString; // excerpted string

    [archiver encodeObject: someString withKey: @"someString"]
}
```

Comment: What about implementing `NSCoding` protocol in `MyObjects`'s category?

Comment: @JakubVano Yes, that's what I'm trying right now.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to encode the extracted excepts as an array:

```
NSMutableArray *extractedStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
for (MyObject *object in myObjects) {
    [extractedStrings addObject:object.someString];
}
[archiver encodeObject:extractedStrings forKey:@"extractedStrings"];
```

Comment: Tx. That's what I would call an intermediate representation. I real life I am dealing with several fields (not just single strings), so it gets relatively messy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a category that conforms to `NSCoding` has proved to be the best solution in this case:

```
@interface MyClass (Coding) <NSCoding>
// ...
```